# How can I force a long link to wrap?

Tags: html, css

When a link is longer than the width of its container, it overflows. Can it be made to wrap instead?

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
https://one.two.three.four.five.com/this/is/a/really/long/link/which/overflows
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut erat dui, fringilla sit amet semper ut, tristique ut nulla. Sed turpis quam, tincidunt ac pellentesque eu, tristique nec elit. Nam placerat vitae nisi in blandit. Quisque magna purus, facilisis rhoncus pulvinar in, pretium id magna. Aenean magna arcu, maximus eu metus sit amet, tempor laoreet turpis. In consectetur, purus in laoreet laoreet, odio nisi hendrerit erat, et blandit lectus augue et massa. Vestibulum non mauris consectetur, elementum urna vitae, convallis tellus. Vivamus vehicula interdum ligula eu tempus. Nunc accumsan semper sem, sed vestibulum tortor porttitor vulputate. Nam efficitur turpis a justo consectetur dignissim. Integer justo elit, bibendum et neque eget, porttitor lobortis elit. Etiam scelerisque risus quam, non suscipit odio varius id. Curabitur magna purus, pellentesque ut vehicula non, viverra in turpis. Integer sollicitudin suscipit augue id accumsan. Fusce condimentum nisi non suscipit auctor. Integer luctus odio id purus gravida iaculis.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `word-wrap: break-word`.

```css
div {
  font-family: monospace;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
}
.wrap-me {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
https://one.two.three.four.five.com/this/is/a/really/long/link/which/overflows
</p>
<p class="wrap-me">
https://one.two.three.four.five.com/this/is/a/really/long/link/which/wraps
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut erat dui, fringilla sit amet semper ut, tristique ut nulla. Sed turpis quam, tincidunt ac pellentesque eu, tristique nec elit. Nam placerat vitae nisi in blandit. Quisque magna purus, facilisis rhoncus pulvinar in, pretium id magna. Aenean magna arcu, maximus eu metus sit amet, tempor laoreet turpis. In consectetur, purus in laoreet laoreet, odio nisi hendrerit erat, et blandit lectus augue et massa. Vestibulum non mauris consectetur, elementum urna vitae, convallis tellus. Vivamus vehicula interdum ligula eu tempus. Nunc accumsan semper sem, sed vestibulum tortor porttitor vulputate. Nam efficitur turpis a justo consectetur dignissim. Integer justo elit, bibendum et neque eget, porttitor lobortis elit. Etiam scelerisque risus quam, non suscipit odio varius id. Curabitur magna purus, pellentesque ut vehicula non, viverra in turpis. Integer sollicitudin suscipit augue id accumsan. Fusce condimentum nisi non suscipit auctor. Integer luctus odio id purus gravida iaculis.
</p>
</div>
```